# Why does browser fail to connect with IPV6 off?

Tags: networking

Used this guide to stop ipv6 leak https://www.leowkahman.com/2016/03/19/disable-ipv6-raspberry-raspbian/
When VPN is disabled there is no problem. Leak test shows IPV6 disabled. When VPN is enabled the browser cannot connect to any sites. Browser gives DNS error. Pi4 Raspios booting ssd Vivaldi browser Thanks VPN blocks all connections with IPV6 disabled.

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.27.112.1 dev tun0
default via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.2 metric 202
10.27.112.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.27.112.252
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.27.112.1 dev tun0
154.21.114.171 via 192.168.0.1 dev eth0
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.0.2 metric 202

Usage: ip [ OPTIONS ] OBJECT { COMMAND | help }
       ip [ -force ] -batch filename
where  OBJECT := { link | address | addrlabel | route | rule | neigh | ntable |
                   tunnel | tuntap | maddress | mroute | mrule | monitor | xfrm |
                   netns | l2tp | fou | macsec | tcp_metrics | token | netconf | ila |
                   vrf | sr }
       OPTIONS := { -V[ersion] | -s[tatistics] | -d[etails] | -r[esolve] |
                    -h[uman-readable] | -iec | -j[son] | -p[retty] |
                    -f[amily] { inet | inet6 | ipx | dnet | mpls | bridge | link } |
                    -4 | -6 | -I | -D | -M | -B | -0 |
                    -l[oops] { maximum-addr-flush-attempts } | -br[ief] |
                    -o[neline] | -t[imestamp] | -ts[hort] | -b[atch] [filename] |
                    -rc[vbuf] [size] | -n[etns] name | -a[ll] | -c[olor]}
```

Comment: Edit in the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf` when the "VPN is enabled the browser cannot connect to any sites. Browser gives DNS error".

Comment: Why do you think you need to disable IPv6? Do you not think that in the **twenty five** years since IPv6 was invented that it had reached some level of maturity and might, actually, be some orders of magnitude better than IPv4?

Comment: Dougie the answer to your question is the start of my post

Comment: You know, if the problem is that the traffic isn't being routed properly, this isn't I think a "natural consequence" of the difference between ipv6 and ipv4.  IPv4 addresses all have IPv6 equivalents, so you should be able to explicitly route all IPv6 traffic through the VPN -- although if that's true the VPN provider should have been smart enough to configure this for you, the amount of stupid in the world is not something to underestimate.   Edit in the output of `ip route` and `ip -6 route` and I might be able to suggest something to try.  Either your problem is solved or I eat my words.

Comment: WRT your `resolv.conf`, this is probably from your ISP (Comcast?) not the VPN provider.  You might try removing or commenting out the IPv6 addresses in there and see what happens.

Comment: From a lot of searching. Tried forcing ipv4, thread here, to no avail. With no VPN and, ipv6 off, there is no problem. Add VPN and, nothing. Seems it's openvpn forcing ipv6.

Comment: Found work around. Got browser ap so I at least have safe browsing. Looks like best I can do for now.